# Do I need a Full crawl search, if i am having an incremental crawl every 20 minutes

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, crawling, search-scope

I have set an incremental  crawl rule to execute an incremental crawl every 20 minutes. But my question is do I need to perform a full crawl, beside the incremental  crawl ? 
Regards

Comment: thanks , but incremental crawl , will be able to detect newly added data such as items, document, calender events, etc..

Comment: See here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/02/18/sharepoint-2010-2013-search-incremental-crawl-vs-full-crawl.aspx, so basically much data will be accurate without a full crawl. But not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full crawl is needed to collect the items the incrementals don't catch. Items like manage properties and security updates on file shares are not considered in incremental searches. Also, a full crawl reindexes everything, therefore rebuilding the entire index, which can help reduce the chance of having a corrupted index. Because a full crawl take a lot more time and resources, I usually set them up nightly or weekly at 11p - 1a, depending on other factors (backups, amount of data, other system routines, etc).

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the explain. i have set a full crawl , every day at 1 am.

Comment: Robert and David already added valuable information to this thread. User might find this blog post handy too. http://sannadisarath.blogspot.ca/2011/03/incremental-crawl-vs-full-crawl.html